# mutableDictionary doesn´t transfer objects to next scene in sprite kit

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene

i know there are a few different topics about that and i read all of them but my first skscene won´t transfer my dictionary objects to the next scene.

the first looks like: (touchesBegan) menuScene

```
HelloScene *gameScene1 = [HelloScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
self.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[self.userData setValue:@"1" forKey:@"selectBall"];
[gameScene1.userData setObject:[self.userData objectForKey:@"selectBall"] forKey:@"selectBall"];
[self.view presentScene: gameScene1];
```

and scene two: (initWithSize) gameScene1

```
int setBall = [[self.userData objectForKey:@"selectBall"] intValue];
self.selectBall = setBall;
```

Comment: These are two scenes, both have separate instances of userData. If you want to transfer them, assign the current scene's userData to that of the newly created scene. Just keep in mind that the userData will be nil during init, so move any code that relies on it into the didMoveToView method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [LearnCocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201863/learncocos2d) already mentioned in the comments, you can't access the userData of the first scene in the second scene. So you will have to set the userData to the new scene before opening it:

```
- (void) showNewScene {
      SKView *currentView = (SKView *) self.view;
      SKScene *currentScene = [currentView scene];
      HelloScene *gameScene1 = [HelloScene scene];
      [gameScene1.userData setObject:[currentScene.userData objectForKey:@"1"] forKey:@"selectBall"];
      [currentView presentScene:gameScene1];

 }
```

Then, you can access the userData in the new loaded `gameScene1` with the `objectForKey`-method.

Also you could use NSUserDefaults to save it. The nice part about using that is, that you can use the information everywhere in your app:

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"1";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"selectBall"];
```

If you want to get it back, just call your userdefaults again:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"selectBall"];
```

Comment: thank you, it works. but is it also possible or even more efficient to save data like scores and userdefaults in the view controller itself. because in my game it is just one. i´m new to this and i have still a few problems with the logic.

Comment: @NeoGER89 I've added the NSUserDefaults-option to my answer.